# backpack for laravel add new field in permission manager

Tags: laravel-5, laravel-backpack

I need to add a new field named username when registering or adding a new user, so i mess with permissionmanager folder inside vendor since i have no idea how to extend it from outside the vendor folder.

```
    [
             'name'  => 'username',
             'label' => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.username'),
             'type'  => 'text',
     ],
```

thats' what i got:

[image: image new field]

I also put the language conversion in resources\views\vendor\backpack\permissionmanager\src\resources\lang\es with no success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the latest version of PermissionManager you can overwrite the routes. This way, you can point to your own PermissionCrudController, which would extend the PermissionCrudController from the package. Inside your PermissionCrudController you can do anything you want - including adding a new field. Your setup method could look something like this:

```
public function setup()
{
  parent::setup();

  $this->crud->addField([
             'name'  => 'username',
             'label' => trans('backpack::permissionmanager.username'),
             'type'  => 'text',
     ])->after('name');
}
```

Check out [the documentation for this here](https://github.com/laravel-backpack/permissionmanager#overwriting-functionality).

---

The language file should NOT be in the views folder. In should be in the LANG folder: `resources\lang\vendor\backpack\es\permissionmanager.php`.